# The Dyadic Partition is finer when m>n

Tags: real-analysis

Given: For each $n\in \Bbb N$, $P_n = \{j/2^n : j = 0,1,...2^n\}$ is a partition of the interval [0,1].
Prove: $P_m$ is finer than $P_n$ when $m>n$

Attempt at proof: Since $m>n$, we have $2^m>2^n$. This implies that $P_m = \{j/2^m : j = 0,1,...2^n,..,2^m\}$.Thus $\forall$ $x\in P_n$, we have $x \in P_m$.
Thus $P_n \subset P_m$. Thus $P_m$ is finer than $P_n$.

Is my proof correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear why $x\in P_n\implies x\in P_m$.

Try putting $j=k\cdot 2^{m-n}$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,2^n$ in the second partition.

Do you have to prove that $P_m$ is *strictly* finer? If you have to, consider $1/2^m$.

Comment: It just says finer.

Comment: How does putting $j=k.2^(m-n)$ help? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If $x=k\cdot2^{m-n}/2^m$, $ x \in P_m$, but $x$ is also $k/2^n$, so $x\in P_n$.